# Не правильно выгружается справочник из 1с на сайт

Tags: битрикс, 1с

Может кто нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой: есть реквизит характеристик Цвет фасада и у него есть значение красный, синий и  черный. Почему то после выгрузки на сайт значение цвета фасада записываются в отдельное свойство Attributes (тип строка), а свойство Цвет фасада выгрузилось как справочник но пустое и цвета туда не записались. Почему то не записывается свойство в Highload-блоки хотя все галочки стоят. Некоторые свойства вообще не выгрузились например ЦветЦвет.
Я использую 1С:ERP управление предприятием 2 и модуль обмена Модуль для: "ERP Управление предприятием 2" релиз 2.5.6.124 версия Версия модуля 7.0.2.0.
﻿Попробовала выгрузить в тестовый чистый сайт все выгрузилось как надо.
﻿В чем может быть проблема?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Чистый тестовый сайт - зеркало того, в который выгружаете?

Comment: У вас стоят галочки в последней колонке "Не выгружать". Зачем? Читайте что вы отмечаете.

Comment: Еще как вариант сверить настройки обмена в 1С и настройки интеграции со стороны сайта между тестом и боевым. В особенности касается сайта. На чистом скорее всего вы оставили все по-умолчанию, а на бевом видимо что-то меняли. В любом случае ищите отличия в настройках. Также проверьте xml-файлы выгрузки с тестового портала и боевого. Если они отличаются значит у вас разные параметры обмена.

Comment: @Sagittarius нет, просто тестовая версия битрикс и стандартный шаблон

Comment: @NikolajSarry c галочками там все правильно. В логах на сайте выводится ошибка: Произошла ошибка на стороне сервера. Ответ сервера: failure
Error importing metadata.A dictionary name must start with an alphabetical character and can include only letters and digits. А на тестовом такой ошибки нет. Не подскажешь что это может быть?

Comment: @Karina, посмотрите что у вас в вайле XML.

Comment: Какой лог? На какой файл ругается? В логе это все должно быть.

Comment: @Sagittarius в xml Ид свойства не совпадает с символьным котом на сайте, почему то он вставляет туда __1

Comment: @NikolajSarry он ругается на файл offers: Error importing metadata.Dictionary for property [312] Цвет Корпуса was not found. Please check the property settings.

Comment: У вас у свойства "Цвет фасада" нет символьного кода. Почему?

Comment: @NikolajSarry я это и пытаюсь выяснить, он должен сам заполнять этот код  по почему то вместо букв пишет __1 как будто название пустое, хотя оно есть